# I am using Google Maps auto complete with Angular 2, want to retrieve values in Arabic language

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, autocomplete

In my `reactive` form, I am using two inputs one with English and other is Arabic, both use the autocomplete feature in the `google maps API`, I am using the method `.getPlace()`, but even in the Arabic auto complete it always return English values, how do i get the values in different language? I know there is an option in the script tag for choosing the language but that is not an option for me as I am using both languages

```
  arabicAutoComplete() {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.arabicSearch.nativeElement, {
        types: ['address']
      });
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // get the place result
          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
          console.log(place);

          // verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }
          this.arabic_google_address = place.formatted_address ? place.formatted_address : place.name;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: so if you change the script tag to arabic you get the results in arabic?

Comment: yes, but that is not what i want, because it won't be dynamic is there any options?